# How will use multiple fileupload in same Asp net page

Tags: c#

In my Project I add three FileUploder.I have already used UpdatePanel in my page. also            I had given    Updatepanel each fileuploder. My problem is that when I click on the  button Edit,         FileUploader didnot take selected file.I need postfile from every fileuploader.also
I add trigger for the button btnEdit,but on Click event none of the fileuploader  take selcted file.
     How will manage this three file uploder in this page. I   mentioned my code below.

```
<table class="ui-accordion">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
<tr>
      <td align="left" class="style2">
          <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Experience Certificate"></asp:Label>
       </td>
        <td align="left">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>  
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" /><asp:Image ID="Img1" 
            runat="server" Height="33px" Width="36px" />
        </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
     </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
      <td align="left" class="style2">
          <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Experience Certificate"></asp:Label>
       </td>
        <td align="left">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>  
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload3" runat="server" /><asp:Image ID="Img1" 
            runat="server" Height="33px" Width="36px" />
        </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td align="left" class="style2">
          <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Experience Certificate"></asp:Label>
       </td>
        <td align="left">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>  
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /><asp:Image ID="Img1" 
            runat="server" Height="33px" Width="36px" />
        </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <td class="style2">
           <%-- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <asp:Button ID="Button3" class="btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Next" 
                     Height="36px" Width="74px" />&nbsp;--%> 
                 <asp:HiddenField ID="Hfedi" runat="server" Value=" " />
                                 </td>
               <td align="left">                                     
                <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" class="btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Edit" 
                   Height="36px" Width="74px" onclick="btnEdit_Click" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" ForeColor="Red">   </asp:Label>
                   </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
          </ContentTemplate>
           <Triggers>                                   
              <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEdit"/>                                      
              </Triggers>
             </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Just idea, not answer, may be it is better to use Dropzone in your case - http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: does anybody have idea about it?